# Async response to onMessage returns null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium, sendmessage

I am trying to get an asyc response with the chrome messaging system but it always returns the literal value `null`. In the case below the listener gets the value and fetches the key but the value in `response` is always `null`. Even if I take the call to `getKey()` and replace it with a static string `response` is null.

If I respond synchronously with a static string it works as expected. What am I missing about the async response pattern? The sender is a service worker and the reciever is a chrome extension.

```
(async () => {
        const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"});
        console.log("RESPONSE" + response);
      })();
```

The response logic:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  (async function () {
    var key = await getKey();
    sendResponse(key);
  })();

  // return true to indicate you want to send a response asynchronously
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Assuming `key` is a JSON-compatible type, the code is correct, so the problem is elsewhere e.g. maybe you have a second onMessage listener that responds first or `getKey` actually returns null or it's a bug in Chrome. Try uninstalling the extension to clear all possible leftovers and re-install it anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately the answer here was that we had a different listener that was causing a response to be sent but it wasn't using the `sendResponse()` object. We thought that because it wasn't using sendResponse that we would be safe but that was incorrect.